# Qt Aligning contents of top item in combobox

Tags: qt, combobox, alignment

I am working with Qt to create a GUI for a small game theory project I'm working on. I'm using a combobox as a selector for the team. I can align the contents in the dropdown window just fine, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui.comboBox->count(); i++)
{
    ui.comboBox->setItemData(i, Qt::AlignLeft, Qt::TextAlignmentRole);
}
```

I can't figure out how to align the top item that is selected, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA5jd.png). The contents is not aligned to the left and the name even goes off the screen. Does anyone know how I can align this similarly to the contents in the dropdown list?

I already searched online, but I'm having trouble phrasing the question correctly. Furthermore if I go through the options available to me by the autocompleter when typing `ui.combobox->` I don't really see an option that can do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the go to fix, but I solved it by setting an icon size for the combobox. What I think goes wrong is that there is probably some default size set, no matter the size of the icons when adding items. My icons were of size 50x15 and so I added the following lines:

```
QSize size(50, 15);
ui.comboBox->setIconSize(size);
```

Now it is done correctly and gives the correct view.

[image: the correct view]